# Copy value of list not reference

Tags: python

I have a list that i want to compare to after it gets modified. The previous_list = current_list followed by a modification to the current_list. But the issue i have is anytime the current_list is updated, the previous_list is also updated because everything in python is a reference. Ive tried,

```
previous_list = current_list[:]
previous_list = current_list.copy()
previous_list = list(current_list)
```

but none of these work, every time current_list is updated the previous list is updated immediately without reading this line,

```
previous_list = current_list[:]
```

again.

My goal is to have a while loop the runs until the list are equal. Each loop the current_list is modified after the previous_list is updated with the current_value. I thought the solution was using one of the copy methods above to create a copy of the list and assign but maybe that is a reference too then.

Comment: The word for this kind of copy is 'clone'. Clones come in two kinds: shallow and deep.

Comment: The list (the container, not the values) is indeed copied, but the items are not, they are shared by the two lists. This is known as a shallow copy. try `previous_list = copy.deepcopy(current_list)`

Comment: This *list is being copied*. Whatever is inside the list isnt, though, since these are all shallow copies. You need a deep copy. Maybe simply `previous = [x.copy() for x in current]`

Comment: Can you try sharing your code?

Comment: Yes that worked! thank you @flakes

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1,2,3]

l2 = list(l)

id(l)
2860467931976

id(l2)
2860467932424
```

Comment: ARe you showing that previous_list = list(current_list) should work then?

Comment: @John this demonstrates that `list(l)` creates a copy, although, `list(l) is l` is a little clearer in that regard

Answer (score 0):

This list is being copied. Whatever is inside the list isnt, though, since these are all shallow copies. You need a deep copy. Maybe simply previous = [x.copy() for x in current] – juanpa.arrivillaga